# how to restrict submit for approval unless there is a record in child table(Master-detail) application

Tags: apex

I have master record of invoices and line items as detail record.
there is a submit for approval button  inside the application. I should restrict the user to click for approval if there are no line items

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that it's a true master-detail relationship (and not simply a lookup), you can just create a Roll-Up Summary field to count the line items, and set an entry criteria that the Roll-Up Summary field you've created is greater than 0. By specifying the entry criteria this way, the system will tell the user that there's no matching approval process that can be submitted if there are no line items.